# Sudden Insertion Error to a 3 years old table with 5 million of records - Mysql error 1452 - Insert Problem

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've a table with a 5 million of records. **Suddenly Database table stopped inserting a record**. while record exists in parent table and record insertion is same in child table as It supposed to be.

But do not understand what actually happened. I've also make sure by selecting the field from navicat foreign key filter.

**This is the screenshot of insert query in child table** and parent table (select query) where we can see the record.

[image]

Query:

```
INSERT INTO payment_covered_by ( pay_cov_covered_by_payment_id, pay_cov_payment_id, pay_cov_invoice_id, pay_cov_amount )
VALUES
    ( '10', '10', '1235681', '20.00' );
```

Parent table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `pay_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pay_co_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_customer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_method` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_date` date NOT NULL,
  `pay_total_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `pay_inv_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_inv_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pay_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_method` (`pay_method`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_user_id` (`pay_user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_customer_id` (`pay_customer_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_co_id` (`pay_co_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_inv_id` (`pay_inv_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `payments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_method`) REFERENCES `payments_method` (`paymethod_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `payments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_co_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`co_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `payments_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_customer_id`) REFERENCES `customs` (`custom_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `payments_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2674670 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Child Table

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_covered_by` (
  `pay_cov_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pay_cov_covered_by_payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_cov_payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_cov_invoice_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `pay_cov_amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pay_cov_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_cov_covered_by_payment_id` (`pay_cov_covered_by_payment_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_cov_payment_id` (`pay_cov_payment_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `pay_cov_invoice_id` (`pay_cov_invoice_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `payment_covered_by_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_cov_covered_by_payment_id`) REFERENCES `payments` (`pay_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `payment_covered_by_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_cov_payment_id`) REFERENCES `payments` (`pay_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `payment_covered_by_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`pay_cov_invoice_id`) REFERENCES `invoices` (`inv_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45397 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image]

Comment: The database says the parent record does not exist; you say it does. Who should we believe, and why?

Comment: @mustaccio I've updated the question and here's the link of query as a proof
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMl6m.png

Comment: Why are you inserting character literals into integer and decimal columns? Have you tried using correct data types?

Comment: I've tried by adding a record directly in table editor.

Comment: Are your select and insert queries definitely executed against the same database?

Comment: everything was working fine till last night. no code change happened. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQEEKWmXywM_6YGbRu_OTQARL9keDHNx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @dbdemon yes exactly both are same. even I've also tried by editor directly.

Comment: @mustaccio - (MySQL will happily treat quoted integers as integers if the context requires it.  Removing the quotes won't solve the problem.)

Comment: (Pet peeve:  Prefixing columns names with the table name adds clutter without adding clarity.)

Comment: @RickJames MySQL will happily accept column names prefixed with table names. Renaming columns won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution *may be* to rebuild the indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE payments ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE payment_covered_by ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Caveat:  If the tables are large, they may take a long time.

Comment: before run 1- It is safe? because I've more than 5-10 million of records inside a database. issue is only happening in production. 
2- but what happened sudden?

Comment: Corrupted indexes in InnoDB are extremely rare.  _If_ that is the problem, I have no explanation.  Those 'simple' queries rebuild the indexes.  Feel free to take a full dump of your database first.

Comment: okay dumping and then try

Comment: thank you. 
I run this query, then all is good from last 12 hours.
`ALTER TABLE payment_covered_by ENGINE=InnoDB;`

**But I've a question**
I've updated two old tables (new column added by running Laravel migration) which is directly connected with this table. 
**now I'm curious, Do I've to again run this command every time If I update those tables.**

Comment: @AbdulRehman - You should not need it.  Nor should you have needed it in the first place.  My Answer comes in the category of "if all else fails, do this".

Comment: hi @RickJames. I hope you'll good. If you've some time can you please help me over query optimization issue.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319588/improving-performance-of-group-by-sum-query-to-get-payment-data-based-on-total-e