# Improving Performance of Group By sum Query to get payment data based on total Employees

Tags: mysql, query-performance, group-by, sum

I have a query to show payment data paid by grouped total Employee (1,2,3) (their size [how much number of users are in total Employee)) and the total amount.

**But My query took 30-35 seconds**

result screenshot is attached too.

Actually instead of add filters (having totalEmployee in (1,2,3,4,5) in inner query, I want to manage in only one call to load all the data.

```
SELECT  
    tmp.total_emp AS totalEmployee,
    COUNT( DISTINCT outerCompany.co_id ) AS companySize,
    SUM( pay_amount ) AS totalAmount
FROM
    company outerCompany
    INNER JOIN 
    ( 
    SELECT innerCompany.co_id, COUNT(*) AS total_emp FROM company innerCompany 
    LEFT JOIN users ON innerCompany.co_id = user_company_id GROUP BY innerCompany.co_id 
    ) tmp ON outerCompany.co_id = tmp.co_id
    LEFT JOIN payments ON outerCompany.co_id = pay_co_id 
GROUP BY
    totalEmployee
ORDER BY
    totalEmployee ASC;
```

Result
[image]

Explain
[image]

I've tried many things but I'm far away from optimization.
1- only holding users query inside subQuery instead of innercompany/users.
2. I've also exclude outer company and only picks tmp result.

*Last rows of data screenshot*

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Please change some names; I am having trouble understanding the goal.  "companySize" -> numberOfCompanies"?; "user" -> "employee"?  And, as a further sanity check, please show us the last few lines of the output (with the biggest companies).

Comment: For example, companies of 8 employees average 2.7 million dollars (or whatever the unit is).  Yet for 1 employee it is more like 15K.

Comment: Thank you for reply. 
companySize -> is number of companies. 
Employee -> is like sub_user/multiple user belongs to one company.

Comment: @RickJames new screenshot is attached with the last rows. I've also added inner query result in the same screenshot.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the 3 tables.

Comment: Create table screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQNTA.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.

- Switch LEFT JOIN to subquery
- Simply derived table (and move LEFT out)
- Suggest indexes

revised query

```
SELECT  counts.total_emp AS totalEmployee,
        COUNT( DISTINCT oC.co_id ) AS companySize,
        ( SELECT SUM(p.pay_amount) 
               FROM payments AS p
               WHERE p.pay_co_id = oC.co_id
        ) AS totalAmount
    FROM  company AS oC
    LEFT JOIN  
        ( SELECT  u.user_company_id, COUNT(*) AS total_emp
            FROM  users AS u
            GROUP BY  u.user_company_id
        ) AS counts  ON oC.co_id = counts.user_company_id
    GROUP BY  counts.total_emp
    ORDER BY  counts.total_emp ASC;
```

Plus indexes:

```
p:  INDEX(pay_co_id,  pay_amount)
u:  INDEX(user_company_id)
```

Comment: actually in left join Inside. I previously put same users query but that's not worked too. 
Let me again share most of Important things. 
All have indexes. I can share in a while in link.

1- Users have *55K* records 
2- Company have *40k* records, 
3- Payments have *6300k* records

so The previous query shows explain 38k records from whole table (from above image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nZDL.png

Comment: I'm just try to think  either does this type of records took 30 seconds is a valid time. I think I'm doing some mistake
 (
I've also one alternate solution to manage by divide totalEmployee in chunks like this Inside left join subquery having COUNT() in (1,2,3)*. This type will increase work but reduced some seconds and load data in 15 seconds.
e.x: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEzJi.png

Comment: Thank you. *(pay_co_id,  pay_amount)*  by adding only this index helps me. The Page is super fast. It loads the data in 7-8 seconds. thank you so much.

Previously pay_co_id indexed but I added pay_amount separately. but adding composite It resolved my problem.